# In an production env, how many flows does K8 Pod have any point of time

Tags: networking, kubernetes

I am looking for ball park numbers in production for following questions

1) How many flows(5 tuple: SRC-IP, DEST-IP, SRC-PORT, DEST-PORT, Protocol) does a pod open and how long these flow live ?.

2) When one moves from VM's to containers with K8, Is it typical to convert a VM in to a Pod ?

Are there any studies around this area ?. If so, can you provide pointers ?

Answer (score 0):

1:

It depends on how many containers or connections your pod will make.

2: 
It is definitely different thing:
[Pod](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod/)  is a group of containers which is managed by K8s. VM is a Virtual Machine, you can't convert VM into a pod.

Usually, when you migrate from VMs to K8s, you change the architecture of your application.